# How to parse strings in a table cell generated by format-table in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I used the following comlet to get the data:

```
import-csv .\ConnectionStrings.txt -Delimiter "`t" -Header Firms, URLs, Config, Type | format-table -Property Firms, URLs -HideTableHeaders -outvariable content

#Not working part
for($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Count; $i++){
    $url = $content[$i][1]    
    $instance = $url.SubString(0, $url.IndexOf(".") - 1)
}
```

and below it is the result from import-csv... cmdlet:

```
value1    url1.test.com
value2    url2.test.com
value3    urle3.test.com
...
valuen    urln.test.com
```

I used getType to check $content and it's ArrayList. I thought I could use it as a C# ArrayList because I need to parse the second column to get the url section. 
But not working. Currently I think I am in a dead end without any idea where I can go...

Comment: Please include the powershell code that is not working, a description of what it is doing, and a description of what you're expecting to see as best you can.

Comment: @PaulHicks Hi I've added the code, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `format-table` is for displaying an object as a textual table. But you want to access the innards of the object that `import-csv` has given you. So you don't want `format-table`.
2. `$content` is an ArrayList of objects that `import-csv` has built, not an ArrayList of ArrayLists or of arrays. You have told `import-csv` what kind of object to build using the `-Header` option, so just use that.
3. SubString takes a start index and a length, not a start index and an end index.

Making the relevant changes, I get this code:

```
$content = import-csv .\ConnectionStrings.txt -Delimiter "`t" -Header Firms, URLs, Config, Type 

for($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Count; $i++){
    $url = $content[$i].URLs
    $instance = $url.SubString(0, $url.IndexOf("."))
    Write-Host $instance
}
```

Which gives this output:

```
url1
url2
urle3
urln
```

Which is what you are looking for, I think.

Comment: Hi Paul,Thanks for your answer. It's really helpful. Just one last question, what's wrong with -outvariable in my original code?

Comment: Nothing. It's correctly putting the object that formats tables nicely into `$content`. The problem is that you don't want an object that formats other objects into tables: you want those other objects directly.

Comment: My previous comment is slightly hard to parse. Consider this analogy: `import-csv -Header x, y, z` creates something equivalent to a spreadsheet, in that you can navigate around it, change values in it, inspect other values, etc. `format-table -outvariable content` then converts that spreadsheet into a PDF file. All you can do with it is print it out.

Comment: Hi @PaulHicks, Thanks for the explanation, really helpful